# How to batch convert Shapefiles to GMLs?

Tags: python, shapefile, gml, batch

I know how to do this within Quantum GIS but I have 30+ shapefiles that need to be converted to GML.  Is there a Python script sample or plugin for Quantum GIS that I can use to convert my shapefiles to GML?

Comment: Depending on your QGIS install you probably have [GDAL/OGR](http://www.gdal.org/) installed already. You could then create a quick batch process from [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) to do the job - after all, that's what QGIS is using the the background anyway.

Comment: `ogr2ogr seg.shp pla.gml segments` does it not work for you?

Comment: How to convert `SHP` into `GML` in `OS VerctorMap Local` format?

Comment: @om_henners could you add your comment as an answer so the question can be marked as solved if the OP agrees?

Comment: OS? Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 3):

With the installation of QGIS you will have the [GDAL/OGR](http://gdal.org) libraries installed. OGR supports both shapefiles and GML (and many other vector formats). You can then create a batch process from [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) to perform the transformation.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this from the command-line shell using `ogr2ogr` ‒ that is, outside QGIS. E.g. on GNU/Linux with bash:

```bash
cd /path/to/shapefiles
for file in $(ls *.shp); 
   do 
     ogr2ogr "$file" `basename "$file" .shp`.gml; 
   done
```

That would be a **`“batch process”`** as mentioned in some comments to this same question.